# Xamarin.Forms Bind Parent Property with Child's in XAML

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have search for two days and can't find a answer for this problem. I have a Simple Content Page, with one Bindable Property:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MainTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create<Page1 , string>(p => p.MainText, string.Empty);

    public string MainText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(MainTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MainTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML, I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Test.Pages.Page1">
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="0"/>    
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="1"/>
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="2"/>
<ctrl:CustomControl CustomProperty="{Binding MainText}" />
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

In Custom Control, is something like that:

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label x:Name="lbl1" />
</StackLayout>
```

And in the code Behind, I use the OnPropertyChanged to set the value received between the CustomProperty and the lbl1. The CustomProperty is defined as the same way as I have defined the MainTextProperty.

However , this is not working. I looked for any kind of example that would allow me doing anything like that, but I have not found. Any of you know how I can accomplish something like that? I'm receiving problems of type mismatch between the value that I pass and Xamarin.Forms.Binding.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use x:Reference. In this case you don't update page's data context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Page1"
             x:Name="root">
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=root}"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" Grid.Row="3"/>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I added the Binding Context as you said, but I received a exception of Type Mismatch.

Comment: I tested this xaml in my sample project, it was fine.
Here you can find more about view-to-view bindings in Xamarin.Forms http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/
Could you attach your sample project?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add `BindingContext`? I tried below and it works

```
    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        BindingContext = this;
        MainText = "123";
    }
```

I saw your class was named as **`Page1`**, then the `Declarer` in `BindableProperty` should also be **`Page1`** instead of  **`HomePage`**.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MainTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create<Page1, string>(p => p.MainText, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Struggle in this issue for sometime and discover that the returned type of the binding is not string it should be **Binding** BTW BindableProperties with generic types has deprecated so your code should be like:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MainTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MainText",typeof(Binding), typeof(Page1),null);

    public Binding MainText
    {
        get
        {
            return (Binding)GetValue(MainTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MainTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```